# How do detect which submit button was sent through POST in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, submit

**Problem:**

To detect with jQuery which submit button was pressed after the form is sent through PHP.

**Scenario:**

I have three buttons:

1. submit-update1
2. submit-update2
3. submit-update3

If $_POST['submit-update1'] is set in PHP then jQuery should add a class to a div with id "collapseOne". For instance:

```
if (PHP POST submit button 1 is submitted)
{
    $('#collapseOne').addClass('in');
}

if (PHP POST submit button 2 is submitted)
{
    $('#collapseTwo').addClass('in');
}

if (PHP POST submit button 3 is submitted)
{
    $('#collapseThree').addClass('in');
}
```

**DIV elements:**

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
          Title 1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Text here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
          Title 2
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Text here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
          Title 3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Text here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Submit buttons:**

```
<button type="submit" id="submit-update1" name="submit-update1">Update 1</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit-update2" name="submit-update2">Update 2</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit-update3" name="submit-update3">Update 3</button>
```

Any advice is welcome and thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using ajax to post the form data?

Comment: @thecodeparadox HTML code available now.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield Form data is submitted using PHP POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <form method="post" id="many_buttons">
    <input type="hidden" id="submit_button" name="button_pressed" />

    <button type="submit" id="submit-update1" name="submit-update1">Update 1</button>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-update2" name="submit-update2">Update 2</button>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-update3" name="submit-update3">Update 3</button>
  </form>

  <script>
  $('#many_buttons button[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $('#submit_button').val($(this).attr('name'))
  })
  </script>
```

Then in server side:

```
  <?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $button = $_POST['button_pressed'];

    if ($button == 'submit-update1')
      $div = 'collapseOne';
    elseif ($button == 'submit-update2')
      $div = 'collapseTwo';
    elseif ($button == 'submit-update3')
      $div = 'collapseThree';
  }
  ?>
```

Finally you print this javascript:

```
  <?php if (!empty($div)) : ?>
  <script>$('#<?php echo $div ?>').addClass('in')</script>
  <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I kindly appreciate the guidance and your time!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already have the post submit button thing figured out but are having trouble manipulating the page based on those variables. You could use a dynamic script to set some variables based on the post variables like so:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
if (isset($_POST['submit-update1']) && $_POST['submit-update1'] == true) {
    echo "var submitUpdate1 = true;";
}
else {
    echo "var submitUpdate1 = false;";
}
///...do similar things for the rest of your post variables
echo "</script>";
```

Then in your javascript you would simply access those variables defined above after the document is ready.

Comment: In other words, there isn't a built in function in jQuery to detect what button was sent and then act on that?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="" />
```

And then this is the jQuery:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    $('form input[name="submit"]').val($(this).attr('name'));
    $('form').serialize();
});
```